# Parsing multiple JSON objects that exist in one line in Java

Tags: java, json, regex, api, omdbapi

I'm currently using the OMDB API, which can either return get-queries as JSON objects or XML. Working with JSON is something I'd like to learn, and it generally seems like best solution for what I'm trying to do. The implementation I'm hoping for, is to allow the user to search for a movie, and select the correct one from a list. I'm currently using the google.gson library.

The problem I've run in to, is that the searching for movies by a title with OMDB, this example being "batman", returns the following String:

```
{"Search":[{"Title":"Batman Begins","Year":"2005","imdbID":"tt0372784","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTY4YjI2N2MtYmFlMC00ZjcyLTg3YjEtMDQyM2ZjYzQ5YWFkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice","Year":"2016","imdbID":"tt2975590","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYThjYzcyYzItNTVjNy00NDk0LTgwMWQtYjMwNmNlNWJhMzMyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman","Year":"1989","imdbID":"tt0096895","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwNjAyODIyMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDMwMDk2._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman Returns","Year":"1992","imdbID":"tt0103776","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGZmYzVkMmItM2NiOS00MDI3LWI4ZWQtMTg0YWZkODRkMmViXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODY0NzcxNw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman Forever","Year":"1995","imdbID":"tt0112462","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDdjYmFiYWEtYzBhZS00YTZkLWFlODgtY2I5MDE0NzZmMDljXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman & Robin","Year":"1997","imdbID":"tt0118688","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMGQ5YTM1NmMtYmIxYy00N2VmLWJhZTYtN2EwYTY3MWFhOTczXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTA2NTI0MTY@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"The Lego Batman Movie","Year":"2017","imdbID":"tt4116284","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTcyNTEyOTY0M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTAyNzU3MDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman: The Animated Series","Year":"1992–1995","imdbID":"tt0103359","Type":"series","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTM3MTRkZjQtYjBkMy00YWE1LTkxOTQtNDQyNGY0YjYzNzAzXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyOTgwMzk1MTA@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman: Under the Red Hood","Year":"2010","imdbID":"tt1569923","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNmY4ZDZjY2UtOWFiYy00MjhjLThmMjctOTQ2NjYxZGRjYmNlL2ltYWdlL2ltYWdlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman: The Dark Knight Returns, Part 1","Year":"2012","imdbID":"tt2313197","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzIxMDkxNDM2M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5ODY1OQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"}],"totalResults":"490","Response":"True"}
```

Thus far, I've managed to remove the `{"Search":[` and `],"totalResults":"490","Response":"True"}` part using `sendGetRequest(requestURL).substring(11, sendGetRequest(requestURL).length()-41);`, yet I still can't seem to parse the String as JSON. I've tried using String.split and Matcher/Pattern with various regexes, to separate the the JsonObjects. I've also tried a JSONArray, but to no avail.

I'm new to working with JSON, so it's not unlikely I'm missing something obvious or have completely misunderstood JSON in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define a new custom class for your need:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class YourClass {
    @JsonProperty("Title")
    private String title;
    @JsonProperty("Year")
    private String year;
    private String imdbID;
    @JsonProperty("Type")
    private String type;
    @JsonProperty("Poster")
    private String poster;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getImdbID() {
        return imdbID;
    }

    public void setImdbID(String imdbID) {
        this.imdbID = imdbID;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getPoster() {
        return poster;
    }

    public void setPoster(String poster) {
        this.poster = poster;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "YourClass{" +
                "title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", year='" + year + '\'' +
                ", imdbID='" + imdbID + '\'' +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", poster='" + poster + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Then simply you can parse your JSON, this is ***main method***:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);


    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    List<YourClass> yourClassList = objectMapper.readValue("[{\"Title\":\"Batman Begins\",\"Year\":\"2005\",\"imdbID\":\"tt0372784\",\"Type\":\"movie\",\"Poster\":\"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTY4YjI2N2MtYmFlMC00ZjcyLTg3YjEtMDQyM2ZjYzQ5YWFkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg\"},{\"Title\":\"Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice\",\"Year\":\"2016\",\"imdbID\":\"tt2975590\",\"Type\":\"movie\",\"Poster\":\"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYThjYzcyYzItNTVjNy00NDk0LTgwMWQtYjMwNmNlNWJhMzMyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg\"},{\"Title\":\"Batman\",\"Year\":\"1989\",\"imdbID\":\"tt0096895\",\"Type\":\"movie\",\"Poster\":\"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwNjAyODIyMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDMwMDk2._V1_SX300.jpg\"},{\"Title\":\"Batman Returns\",\"Year\":\"1992\",\"imdbID\":\"tt0103776\",\"Type\":\"movie\",\"Poster\":\"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGZmYzVkMmItM2NiOS00MDI3LWI4ZWQtMTg0YWZkODRkMmViXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODY0NzcxNw@@._V1_SX300.jpg\"},{\"Title\":\"Batman Forever\",\"Year\":\"1995\",\"imdbID\":\"tt0112462\",\"Type\":\"movie\",\"Poster\":\"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDdjYmFiYWEtYzBhZS00YTZkLWFlODgtY2I5MDE0NzZmMDljXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg\"},{\"Title\":\"Batman & Robin\",\"Year\":\"1997\",\"imdbID\":\"tt0118688\",\"Type\":\"movie\",\"Poster\":\"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMGQ5YTM1NmMtYmIxYy00N2VmLWJhZTYtN2EwYTY3MWFhOTczXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTA2NTI0MTY@._V1_SX300.jpg\"},{\"Title\":\"The Lego Batman Movie\",\"Year\":\"2017\",\"imdbID\":\"tt4116284\",\"Type\":\"movie\",\"Poster\":\"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTcyNTEyOTY0M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTAyNzU3MDI@._V1_SX300.jpg\"},{\"Title\":\"Batman: The Animated Series\",\"Year\":\"1992–1995\",\"imdbID\":\"tt0103359\",\"Type\":\"series\",\"Poster\":\"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTM3MTRkZjQtYjBkMy00YWE1LTkxOTQtNDQyNGY0YjYzNzAzXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyOTgwMzk1MTA@._V1_SX300.jpg\"},{\"Title\":\"Batman: Under the Red Hood\",\"Year\":\"2010\",\"imdbID\":\"tt1569923\",\"Type\":\"movie\",\"Poster\":\"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNmY4ZDZjY2UtOWFiYy00MjhjLThmMjctOTQ2NjYxZGRjYmNlL2ltYWdlL2ltYWdlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg\"},{\"Title\":\"Batman: The Dark Knight Returns, Part 1\",\"Year\":\"2012\",\"imdbID\":\"tt2313197\",\"Type\":\"movie\",\"Poster\":\"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzIxMDkxNDM2M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5ODY1OQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg\"}]", new TypeReference<ArrayList<YourClass>>() {});

    for (YourClass yourClass: yourClassList) {
        System.out.println(yourClass);
    }
}
```

***P.S:*** Keep in your mind that you must not remove brackets `[]` from your JSON as you said in your question.

Comment: This solution will work when you will add `@jsonProperty` on the fields keeping in mind that the field name in json string should match to argument in `@jsonProperty` annotation

Comment: If class properties are same as JSON keys, doesn't necessary to add JsonProperty annotation @Nitika

Comment: Thank you! I'm assuming you're using Jackson. Although I ran into the following exception: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<Movie>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)`. I also tried adding @JsonProperty as @Nitika suggested, but had the same result.

Comment: @Zonus I think you removed brackets from your JSON. your JSON string must be in this format: [{"Title":"Batman Begins", ...},{"Title":"Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice", ...}]   . I tested this solution, if you get error again tell me and I will put the complete answer here

Comment: @Zonus I edit my answer and now you can check the complete solution

Comment: @MehdiRahimi Thank you! I finally got it working. the problem seems to have been a misunderstanding on my part in regards to the braces. I had thought you meant that I should also keep the `"Search":` part, but that wasn't the case.